# Powershell: Find out what a character is in a string

Tags: csv, powershell

I have a problem where I am getting these space like characters in between each character when I import from csv. The easy work around for this is changing the csv encoding to ansi/ascii but this will only take when opening the file and saving as then specifying the encoding. I have tried:

`(Get-Content -Path $path) | Out-file -FilePath $path -Encoding "ASCII"`)

Which at first I thought worked but it was because I had previously done the save as on the file and forgot about it.

The csv I am Importing looks like this before its imported.

`C:\temp,C:\temp,17.2MB, 0`

But when the csv is imported the space like characters get involved:

[image: Screen]

I dont know how well you can see it in that image but the text is:

`C : \ t e m p, C : \ t e m p, 1 7 . 2 M B,  0`

This space is stopping me from searching on my data.

Basically is there a way to find out what that character is so I can get rid of it? Or is there another way to change the encoding?

Comment: `Get-Content` tries to guess the encoding used for the file -- it doesn't necessarily guess correctly. Does `Get-Content -encoding Unicode` improve matters?

Comment: No it doesn't, is there anyway to change the encoding in powershell if that just gets the encoding?

Comment: It doesn't "get" the encoding -- `Get-Content -encoding Unicode -Path $path` *tells* PowerShell the file is encoded as (little-endian) Unicode. If that's not the encoding of the file, it won't work (from your output, it looks like it might have been). You have to know a file's encoding before you can read it.

Answer (score 1):

It's hard for us to answer what encoding you have when we don't have access to the file, but it's clear that the encoding the file is saved as uses more bits (ex 16/32bit) then the encoding PowerShell guessed it was (ex. 7/8bit since you didn't specify an encoding).

Try out different encodings in your `Import-CSV`-command using `Import-CSV -Path Myfile.csv -Encoding Unicode` (UTF16), `-Encoding UTF32` etc..

Comment: Unfortunately the version of powershell we are running has no -Encoding on Import-CSV so that will not work. Its not possible to upgrade powershell either

Comment: Then use `Get-Content -Path MyFile.csv -Encoding Unicode | ConvertFrom-CSV`. Whoever wrote the file knows what encoding is being used..

Comment: Yeah I have asked them what encoding is used, just waiting for a response. As I am using an external program to produce the csv file I was hoping I could just change the encoding on powershell as I don't know what it currently is. Worst part is when this csv is opened in excel or notepad its fine, its just powershell that is doing this and its what I have to use :(

Comment: You can change the encoding used to read the file.  See the `-Encoding` parameter above.. You just have to try different encodingvalues until you find one that works.. It's just autodetect gone wrong..